# Why does my TextEditor in SwiftUI ignore my .keyboardType?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use a `TextEditor()` in SwiftUI and will need `.keyboardType(.numberPad)`. Unfortunately though, whenever I set this option, for some reason my device and simulator seem to ignore it entirely! It just shows the default keyboard no matter what I set as the keyboard option.

Does anyone know why this might be? I have tested iOS 14.0 and 14.2 Beta with Xcode 12 Beta 2.

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to use the .twitter keyboard. It seems to be an issue with TextEditor as it works fine with TextField. If your number isn't going to be multi line perhaps the TextField would be ok for you?

Comment: Dang I was hoping I was just too stupid to use it properly. I can work with TextField for now but TextEditor would be a lot better as it provides a bigger hitbox inside of Form. Thanks for the answer though. Means I am not the only one and this is probably a bug on apple side. Hope they'll fix it soon. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly workaround using [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)

(FB8816771 is the feedback ID I logged with Apple.)

```swift
private extension View {
    func keyboardType_FB8816771(_ type: UIKeyboardType) -> some View {
        let customise: (UITextView) -> () = { uiTextView in
            uiTextView.keyboardType = type
        }
        
        return introspect(selector: TargetViewSelector.siblingContaining, customize: customise)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone with the fact that TextEditor does not have a Done button...expanding on the answer from Luke Howard above...

```swift
import Introspect

extension View {
    func addDoneButton() -> some View {
        let helper = MainViewHelper()
        
        let customise: (UITextView) -> () = { uiTextView in
            let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,
                                                  y: 0.0,
                                                  width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                                                  height: 44.0))//1
            let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: uiTextView, action: #selector(helper.close))
            toolBar.setItems([flexible, barButton], animated: false)//4
            uiTextView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
            uiTextView.keyboardAppearance = .light
        }
        
        return introspect(selector: TargetViewSelector.siblingContaining, customize: customise)
    }
}

class MainViewHelper {
    @objc func close() {
        
    }
}
```